# Showing $ab+bc+ca\ge 4\sqrt 3 \,S$, where $S$ is the area of the triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the lengths of the sides of a triangle and let S be the area of the triangle. Show that $ab+bc+ca\ge 4\sqrt 3 \,S$.
>
> *Hint: Show that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq xy+yx+xz$ for all real x, y, and z.*

Assuming the Ravi transformation gives $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$, $c=x+z$, we can form some relation between the area of the triangle and the sides. But as discussed below, we are  considering a general triangle, not a right triangle, and trigonometry cannot be used.
Thanks

Comment: Area is $\frac12 ab\sin C$ not $\frac12ab$.

Comment: I assume it was a right-triangle.

Comment: OK, well then all three of your combinations are correct as long as the triangle has three right angles.

Comment: I think I have to use another method, such as Ravi transformation, since my assumption is not a complete notion of the triangle, and your uses trigonometry which is not allowed here.

Comment: If trigonometry is not allowed, please state that clearly in the question.

Comment: Is Heron's formula allowed to be used?

Comment: @cr001 Yes, it can be.

Comment: In general, you get a chain of increasingly stronger inequalities:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca\geq 3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}\geq 2(ab+bc+ca)-a^2-b^2-c^2\geq 4\sqrt{3}S.$$
It's a well-studied problem and you will discover a lot if you search for Finsler-Hadviger inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does not use trigonometry and uses Heron's formula.

Let $x={b+c-a\over 2}, y={c+a-b\over2}, z={a+b-c\over 2}$

Then the inequality becomes

$$(x+y)(y+z)+(y+z)(z+x)+(z+x)(x+y) \geq 4\sqrt{3(x+y+z)xyz}$$

Where the right side is the Heron's formula for area. Expand the left side, the inequality is equivalent to

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3xy+3yz+3zx \geq 4\sqrt{3(x+y+z)xyz}$$

To show this we use the hint $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq xy+yz+zx$, which can be proven easily using Cauchy Inequality $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2+x^2)\geq(xy+yz+zx)^2$

Start from LHS,

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3xy+3yz+3zx $$
$$\geq {1\over 3}(x^2+y^2+z^2)+{2\over 3}(xy+yz+zx)+3xy+3yz+3zx$$
$$={1\over 3}(x+y+z)^2+3xy+3yz+3zx$$
$$\geq 4(^4\sqrt{{1\over 3}(x+y+z)^2\cdot3xy\cdot3yz\cdot3zx})$$
$$=4\sqrt{3(x+y+z)xyz}$$

Comment: Did you insert $$(x+y+z)xyz$$ under the square root because it comes from Heron's formula? Note that the RHS is $4\sqrt{3}S$. So if   $$(x+y+z)xyz$$  is $S$, then it should be outside the square root.

Comment: I combined the square root of $\sqrt{(x+y+z)xyz}$ (which is the Heron formula) and the $\sqrt{3}$ into one square root. $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth recording a trig function based solution here.

Using $S=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A = \frac{1}{2}ac\sin B$, we have the desired inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{ab}{S} + \frac{bc}{S} + \frac{ac}{S}\ge 4\sqrt 3\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{\sin A} + \frac{1}{\sin B} + \frac{1}{\sin C}\ge 2\sqrt 3$$

And since $\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ is convex over $(0, \pi)$, by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we have $$\csc(A)+\csc(B)+\csc(C)\ge 3 \csc(\frac{A+B+C}{3})=3\csc\frac{\pi}{3}=3\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}=2\sqrt 3$$

Comment: A nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

For a general triangle, yes, the trigonometry can still be able to give the  solution:
For the area $S=\frac12 bc\sin A$ ($A$ is the angle from sides $b$ and $c$), we first use cosine law $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$ to get
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2=2\bigl(b^2+c^2-bc\cos A\bigr)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2-4\sqrt3 S&=a^2+b^2+c^2-2bc\sqrt3\sin A\\
&=2\Bigl(b^2+c^2-2bc(\frac12\cos A+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin A)\Bigr)\\
&=2\Bigl(b^2+c^2-2bc\sin(A+\frac{\pi}{6})\\
&\ge2\Bigl(b^2+c^2-2bc\Bigr)\ge0.
\end{align}
It is the maximum of ${\sin(A+\frac{\pi}{6})}$ that makes the last inequality true. But for a general triangle, $A\in(0,\pi)$, it is still valid. The equality holds iff $b=c$ and $A=\frac\pi3.$

**EDIT** *It comes from my collections. But the approach was originally from a book about geometry inequality.*

Comment: you proved a weaker inequality.